# chef create file in user's home directory

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I'm using chef to create a file resource

```
  file "somefile" do
     action :create_if_missing
  end
```

And I want to put this in the user's home directory. I am having two issues:

1. The file is interpreted relative to /, so using ~/ ends up putting the file in /~/
2. I'm launching this chef recipe through vagrant and these files are being created by root. So even if I could get ~/ to work, it would end up in root's home. I don't want to hard code to use the username vagrant since it won't always be that (we may run these with chef client as well), and `node[:user]` appears to be empty.

Is there a way to create a file in the non-root user (in this case vagrant) home directory?

Answer (score 18):

Thread is old, but I faced this problem a moment ago.

You can create attribute for user for example: `default['mycookbook']['user']`

Then in your recipe:

```
user = node['mycookbook']['user'] # user set in cookbook attrubute
# user = node['current_user'] # user running chef cookbook (on provisioned host)

home = node['etc']['passwd'][user]['dir'] # Chef DSL
# home = Dir.home(user) # It's Ruby

file "#{home}/somefile" do
  action :create_if_missing
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because Chef recipes are run by the `root` user. How about this workaround

```
if File.exists? "/vagrant"
  user = "vagrant"
else
  user = "deployer"
end

file "/home/#{user}/foo" do
  ..
end
```

Comment: I agree with this approach, but I would use node attributes you pass in. default[:chef_client][:username]

Comment: Since it may not be run by vagrant, I don't want to hard code that name in the file. Is default[:chef_client][:username] an attribute? Or is there an attribute I can use to get the user?

Comment: it looks like using ENV['PWD'] will get me the working directory, which is the current user's home dir

Comment: Also, SUDO_USER has the username I'm looking for, so I can use that to find the correct home dir

Answer (score 0):

As I understand Chef conception - each recipe should be self contained. That means you should be able to add just one recipe (any of them) into run_list and it should be successfully installed on an empty machine.

What seems to me in your case, you assume that your non-root user already exists on machine, which is in contradiction to my previous statement. Your recipe should include another recipe, that configures your non-root user. Provided you use a data_bag for storing the user (and recipe 'user::my_user' should configure your user), your recipe should look something like that.

```
include_recipe 'user::my_user'
my_user = data_bag_item('user', 'my_user')

file ::File.join( my_user['home'], 'somefile' ) do
  action :create_if_missing
end
```